# Already installed OpenCV but where is the folder?

Tags: software-installation, opencv

I am trying to run this code which requires opencv installed.
https://github.com/yuxng/MDP_Tracking/blob/master/compile.m

One line of the code is below

```
include = ' -I/usr/local/include/opencv/ -I/usr/local/include/ -I/usr/include/opencv/';
```

But my usr/local/include has no opencv ? I used the code `pip install opencv-python` to install OpenCV. Where is my opencv folder ?

Comment: I guess you have to install `libopencv-dev`, e.g. `apt-get install libopencv-dev`.

Comment: I think opencv-python installs python wrappers for openCV, not actuall stuff you need.

Comment: @Thomas i have run the command apt-get install libopencv-dev but i still cant find  the opencv folder ?

Comment: If you, like me, use Synaptic (i prefer it) you can always view "installed files" tab in package properties. This will show where actual files located.

Comment: There should be a `/usr/include/opencv` folder after the installation. That should be sufficient.